# how to stop SMS activity

Tags: android

i want to stop outgoing sms..... plz help me on this

Answer (score 3):

Write your own firmware. You cannot do this from the Android SDK.

Comment: how can i write own firmware?
i want to stop particular selected contact to block outgoing sms 
so can you elaborate ?